# Prove the following determinant.

Tags: determinant

> Prove that :
>   $$\left| 
> \begin {array} 
> c (2bc-a^2) & c^2 & b^2 \\
> c^2 & (2ac-b^2) & a^2 \\ 
> b^2 & a^2 & (2ab-c^2) 
> \end{array}
> \right|
> =D^2.$$
>
> Where 
>   $$D= 
> \left| 
> \begin {array} c a& b &c \\
> b & c & a \\ 
> c& a & b
> \end {array} 
> \right|.$$

It is my problem .I simply expand it but it made complex so I think we need to use several operations.

Comment: I edited the question to properly format the first determinant; please tell me if I have made any mistakes when converting into TeX.

Comment: Is $D$ as what it is? Is the last element in the second row $b$?

Comment: HINT: $$2bc-a^2=b\cdot c-a\cdot a+c\cdot b$$

Comment: It's okay answer was edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $D^2$ as  $ \begin{vmatrix}
 b & c & a\\ 
 c & a & b\\ 
 a & b & c
\end{vmatrix} \times  \begin{vmatrix}
 c & a & b\\ 
 b & c & a\\ 
 -a & -b & -c
\end{vmatrix} $

Proving that $D$ is equivalent to each of the above two determinants is a trivial exercise